# Add Webview at the end of ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, webview

I am trying to add webview at the end of listview in my fragment layout.

Here is my fragment layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTheQueue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt_the_queue"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_queue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTheQueue" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webViewQueue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_queue" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried to add webview to footer of listview .
But getting this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

Help me out.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya : I already mentioned that i amgetting ClassCastException..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

just add your webview to Relative Layout and add this layout to footer of listview.
I was getting this error because layout-params of listview and scrollview are different and not in same tree in android.

Here is code :

```
 WebView lWebView = new WebView(getActivity());
 lWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/queue.html");
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
 relativeLayout.addView(lWebView);
 listQueue.addFooterView(relativeLayout);
```

Comment: Its obvious from the error you have to use relative layout, which you have figure it out yourself.